# Live patching in python

Tags: python, testing, pdb

I have a python test, which setUp function takes a lot of time (a few hours). My test function fails, and to debug it and check how to fix the exception, I use pdb.

Problem is when I have an exception in one line, I fix it with pdb and change the test function, I need to run the test all over again, including the very long setup, in order to get to the next line and check it, and then all over again (it throws an exception, reach it with pdb, fix, etc.).

Is there a way to live patch my script, and to continue to the next line without running the hall script all over again?

Comment: Why does the setup take so long? Can you pickle the data structures created by the setup?

Comment: @PM 2Ring I wish.. No, I can't..

Comment: Why not?

A guess: are you testing software that depends on (complex) hardware? If so, simulate the hardware! Yes, this has a significant up-front cost, but currently you are *not* being a good steward of your boss's money. Your software is basically untestable, a disaster waiting to happen!

Comment: Yes, my setUp does setups an hardware environment, that I need to free for other missions when my test is not running.
Is there no way to live patch? Even C can do that now..

Comment: You're testing the hardware as well as your software. Whatever input you are getting from the hardware, mock it so that the code you are actually testing *thinks* it is accessing the hardware.

Comment: It's not an hardware that's easy to mock. Let's not diverse from the original question - is there a way in Python, like in C for example, to live-patch my code while running it?

Answer (score 0):

## Reloading modules

You can move frequently changing part of your code to separate module and use `importlib.reload` for it. (Before python 3.4 it is `imp.reload`, and in python 2.x it is a built-in function.)

Note though that you should be careful with imports: this code will still use obsolete version of module -

```
import changing
from changing import func1
...
func1()
...
reload(changing)  # ← this will reload import module, but separately imported func1 will remain intact
func1()
```

and this one should work -

```
import changing
...
changing.func1()
...
reload(changing)
changing.func1()  # ← now the new version is called!
```

## Monkey-patching functions

Another method, not so convenient in your particular case, is to move changing code in e.g. top-level function in the module, and then replace that function:

```
# my_module
def changeable():
    # do something

def test_something():
    ...
    changeable()
```

and in pdb:

```
>>> ...
>>> def new_version():
        ... new actions ...
>>> my_module.changeable = new_version
>>> my_module.test_something()  # ← this will use updated changeable()
```